# Angular2 роутинг между двумя модулями

Tags: angular2

Добрый день,  не могу в офдокументации найти исчерпывающий ответ. Помогите, может кто знает, может кто ссыль даст на пример.
Проблема такова. 
A2 stable. Есть два модуля `app.module`со стандартной точкой входа `app.component`
и некий абстрактный `test.module`.
Так вот. 
Есть ли у кого пример роутинга в котором в качестве точки назначения будет указываться  не компонент а непосредственно test.module?

Comment: Модуль не может быть точкой назначения роутинга, т.к. он может содержать не один компонент, а несколько и даже вовсе ни одного, и собсно модули не для того предназначены. Каков может быть юзкейс такого действа, что вы хотите добиться в итоге?

Comment: Спасибо, спустя месяц и почитав документацию я понял что идея была премерзкая

Answer (score 0):

У вашего второго модуля test.module есть главный компонент, к нему и пропишите путь.

Comment: Ничего непонятно...

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день, вы можете реализовать это несколькими вариантами 
Допустим у нас есть структура:
    app/
        app.module.ts
        shared/
          test.module.ts
тогда (укажу только роутинг)

**Вариант 1**
Постоянная загрузка вашего компонента:
Модуль test.module.ts:
    @NgModule({
    ...
    bootstrap: [TestComponent]
    })
    export class TestModule {
    }
Роутинг

```
appRouter: Routes = [
 {
    path: 'test',
    component: TestComponent
  },
]
```

**Вариант 2**

Ленивая загрузка компонента (загрузка модуля по требованию). Настройка роута будет выглядеть примерно так:

appRouter: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'disp',
        loadChildren: './app-disp/app-disp.module#AppDispModule'
    },
]